# Joomla Extention to add pois on google map from database?

Tags: google-maps, joomla

I need a joomla extention that adds a google map on my page and loads pois from a database.

For example i want to have pois on a database with their name , description , position(lat,lot) and the extention to be able to load everything from the database and show on the map.

Is there an extention like that?

Comment: have you looked at the Joomla Extensions Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout zh map it's really powerful
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/maps/16900

or choose another one: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/maps 56 extensions are listed!

Answer (score 0):

While searching for an answer to this question recently, I found some promising solutions.

1. VMap: http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/vmap

VMap "provides you a very simple and flexible way to put anything from your database on a Google Map".

2. Mike Reumer's Google Maps: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-maps-by-reumer

"You can use a table of your database as a source for your markers. You have to write a php function that generates a kml file (see: https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml for details). Then you can add the plugin in an article: {mosmap kml='phpsql_genkml3.php'}."

See http://tech.reumer.net/Google-Maps/Documentation-of-plugin-Googlemap/kml-out-of-database.html for more details.

3. Use the method described in option 2 to generate a kml file and use one of the other extensions that displays kml file data in a Google Map. For example, Phoca Maps will also do this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-maps